# Parcelable - ArrayList<String> NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I'm making my object parcelable so I can use it with `Intent`s. I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when, once received, I'm reading my object's content. Most exactly the content of my `ArrayList<String>`. When iterating over my `ArrayList<String>` it has `null` value in all positions, therefore my `NullPointerException`.

Here's my `Parcelable` class:

```
public class PhoneBackup implements Parcelable{

public Integer id;
public Long ts;
public String device_name;
public String device_manufacturer;
public String device_model;
public Integer backup_contacts_count;
public String description;
public ArrayList<String> backup_contacts;

public PhoneBackup()
{

}


public PhoneBackup(Parcel pc){
//      backup_contacts = new ArrayList<String>(); // Tried this way, still NPE

    id = pc.readInt();
    ts =  pc.readLong();
    device_name = pc.readString();
    device_manufacturer = pc.readString();
    device_model = pc.readString();
    backup_contacts_count = pc.readInt();
    description = pc.readString();
//      pc.readStringList(backup_contacts); // Tried this way, still NPE
    backup_contacts = pc.createStringArrayList();
}

// (getters and setters)

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeLong(ts);
    dest.writeString(device_name);
    dest.writeString(device_manufacturer);
    dest.writeString(device_model);
    dest.writeInt(backup_contacts_count);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeList(backup_contacts);

}

/** Static field used to regenerate object, individually or as arrays */
public static final Parcelable.Creator<PhoneBackup> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PhoneBackup>() {
    public PhoneBackup createFromParcel(Parcel pc) {
        return new PhoneBackup(pc);
    }
    public PhoneBackup[] newArray(int size) {
        return new PhoneBackup[size];
    }
};
```

The `NullPointerException` is with my `backup_contacts`. But `backup_contacts` has the correct size but the containts are all `null` and as I need to read the contents of `backup_contacts` using `get(position)` I receive a `null` value and not a `String`.

Question is, why is the `Parcelable` passing null values to the `ArrayList<String>` and not he actual Strings? How can I fix it?

Comment: **ALWAYS** include the logcat in your question if you get exceptions.

Comment: I understand your comment but the stacktrace would be quite useless here as it was pointing to my app methods with no mention to `PhoneBackup ` class which part of a library I developed. I just manually traced the NPE to `PhoneBackup` thru multiples debugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read a list it should be

```
backup_contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
in.readList(backup_contacts, null);
```

[**Here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readList%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) is the documentation.

The documentation for `createStringArrayList`  says:

> Read and return a new ArrayList containing String objects from the
>   parcel that was written with writeStringList(List)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be in the writing to the parcel :

```
dest.writeList(backup_contacts);
```

should be

```
dest.writeStringList(backup_contacts);
```

> public final void writeStringList (List val) Added in API
>   level 1
>
> Flatten a List containing String objects into the parcel, at the
>   current dataPosition() and growing dataCapacity() if needed. They can
>   later be retrieved with createStringArrayList() or
>   readStringList(List).